# How do you automatically test a time check?

Tags: unit-testing, time

Say you have a property `startTime`. Then you have a method `doSomething`:

```
doSomething() {
   //...stuff
   startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   //... more stuff
}
```

How do you test that `startTime` was assigned correctly? You can't test against an absolute timestamp - it'll likely change between assignment and test. Maybe use a range?

Comment: Why would you want to test whether the assignment was done correctly? Apart from the type of startTime, there's nothing there that could go wrong. Or do you mean whether currentTimeMillis() returns a reasonable value? In that case I would just print it and look.

Comment: I want to make sure that it was assigned/updated in a given code path, period.

Comment: Also this is for an automatic unit test, not visual inspection.

Comment: You mean whether that code path was executed? Because that appears to be the only conceivable reason why it wouldn't be assigned.

Comment: It might not be assigned if *the assignment statment didn't exist*. If the statement got deleted in a refactoring, say...

Comment: If a statement got deleted in a refactoring, lots of things would break.  Test stuff that matters in the end.  Interfaces.  API's.  The final results.

Comment: @S.Lott The reason this question came up is exactly that :) I refactored, this wasn't in the tests, and the whole thing blew up. I want a regression test to prevent it from happening again.

Comment: @Michael: "the whole thing blew up."  Perfect.  Do nothing more.  Tests demonstrated precisely what they were supposed to demonstrate.  Testing is not the same thing as debugging.  Your tests were already perfect.

Comment: @S.Lott Actually I think it passed the tests but blew up when running it... At least that's how I interpret it.

Comment: @Michael If the assignment can cause the application to fail if it doesn't exist, then there should be some other observable property that depends on it. The test should target that property, not a single statement (otherwise you'll need an amount of regression tests equal to the amount of statements in the system).

Comment: @Deckard That is correct - I have tests that set the properties to known values for the calculations using the time, but that couldn't detect the problem when the time was never assigned.

Comment: @Deckard: Hmm, that's right. Not sure what in my particular case, though - it's not touched again in the assigning method.

Comment: @Michael Maybe use a more general sanity check, such as you propose in the question (using a range).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One simple way is to pass in the time from outside the method:

```
doSomething(long currentTime) {
   //...stuff
   startTime = currentTime;
   //... more stuff
}
```

Your production code that calls the method can pass in the real value for System.currentTimeMillis(), whereas your unit test(s) can pass in a specific known value.

Of course, this isn't quite the same as your original. Another possibility that is a little more complex but should mimic the behaviour of your of your original more closely:

```
doSomething(ITimeGetter timeGetter) {
   //...stuff
   startTime = timeGetter.GetCurrentTime;
   //... more stuff
}
```

Define the interface:

```
interface ITimeGetter
{
   long GetCurrentTime();
}
```

Two implementations, one for the production code:

```
class RealTimeGetter implements ITimeGetter
{
  long GetCurrentTime()
  {
      return System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
}
```

One for the unit tests:

```
class TimeGetterForTests implements ITimeGetter
{
  long GetCurrentTime()
  {
     // return a known value.
  }
}
```

Instantiate an ITimeGetter appropriate to your scenario and pass it in to the method you want to test.

Comment: +1 I can think of several use-cases that this method would be perfect for.

Comment: And this is why Dependency Injection and testing go hand in hand :)

Comment: Now, why is an interface that returns the current time called ITime*Setter*?

Comment: Definitely do this by an interface, but use a mocking framework to create your mock object or you will start to get code bloat in your tests and they will become more coupled to your production code than you want and is necessary.

Comment: @Cwan: Stupdity. I've renamed the interface in my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'd use the word `Clock` instead of `TimeGetter`.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Fowler just wrote an interesting [blog](http://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html#Time) post about tests that may fail. He also writes about how you should handle time i.e. by wrapping the System call in a separate object.

Generally speaking, when you communicate with outside resources, for testing and encapsulation, it always helps to wrap them into objects.

Comment: ...and he has a section about time, too! Does seem like a lot of boilerplate to wrap system objects all the time though. I haven't seen a library for that yet. You'd have to write yhour own.

Answer (score 0):

While I personally favor Kramii's answer, there are also frameworks like [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) that allow detouring of static system calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to abstract out the timestamp mechanism so you can mock it.

This will allow you to generate exactly those results from currentTimeMillis that you need for testing, so you can be certain that values are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking may be fine for unit tests, but it's not applicable for system tests.

One of the ways is to assert a range with a few assumptions:
* system clock won't be synchronized by a large value during the test run
* the test would fail if it is executed too slow

Then it's enough to provide two assertions:

```
// event should be created at most 1 minute before the test run, otherwise test would fail
event.creationTimestamp > System.currentTimeMillis() - MINUTES.toMillis(1)
// event should be created before the test runs, may fail if clock synchronizes backwards
event.creationTimestamp < System.currentTimeMillis()
```

And as I noted this is applicable only to the system tests that are fragile by a nature.